# CRONTAB + EXPECT

Tags: cron, expect

I'm new here, I hope they can help me with a problem I have. Thanks ...

I need to run a file with expect through the crontab on the Ubuntu Server.

The following command works:

```
# expect /tmp/teste.sh
```

However the crontab (# crontab -e) does not work:

```
1 * * * * root expect /tmp/teste.sh
```

The content is /tmp/teste.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn mysql -u root -p

expect "password"
send "sssss\n"

expect "mysql"
send "CREATE DATABASE bbbbb;\n"

expect "mysql"
send "exit;\n"

expect eof
exit
```

Could you help me?

Comment: what exactly are you seeing that isn't working?

Comment: Why do you have a `.sh` suffix on an `expect` script? Usually the extension indicates the language the script is written in.

Answer (score 0):

This command works

```
expect /tmp/teste.sh
```

but cron runs it in a specific environment which needs to have a path to your `expect` application.

For me this usually solves the problem:

```
1 * * * * root /path/to/the/binary/expect /tmp/teste.sh
```

Probably you'll need to add the path in the script as well.